# Импортировать содержимое таблиц (ячеек) из xlsx файла в соответствующие SQLite3 таблицы

Tags: python, excel, sqlite3

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test14.db')
cur = con.cursor()
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'abc.xlsx')
sheets = wb.sheetnames

def get_table ():
    for sheet in sheets:
        ws = wb[sheet]
        create_table = 'CREATE TABLE ' + str(sheet) + '(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT'
        for row in next(ws.rows):
            create_table += ', ' + str (row.value) + ' TEXT'
        create_table += ')'
        cur.execute(create_table)


    """ При использование этих переменных для добавления в таблицу, добавление проходит"""
    sql_2 = "INSERT INTO name_1(Number_biulding, Date_pay, Day_fine, Summa) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    sql_3 = (5,5,5,5)

    insert_part_1 = 'INSERT INTO ' + str(sheet) + '('
    insert_part_2 = ''
    insert_value = '(' 

    for col in ws.iter_rows(min_row=0, max_col=4, max_row=1):
        for cell in col:
            cell.value = str(cell.value)
            insert_part_1 += cell.value + ', '
            insert_part_2 += '?, '

    for celt in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=4, max_row=2):
        for val in celt:
            val.value = str(val.value)
            insert_value += val.value + ', '

    insert_part_1 = insert_part_1[:-2]+ ') VALUES ('
    insert_part_2 = insert_part_2[:-2] + ')'
    insert_value = insert_value[:-2] + ')'
    insert = insert_part_1 + insert_part_2

    cur.execute(insert,insert_value)# Не добавляет 
    cur.execute(sql_2,sql_3)# Добавляет

    """
    Запрос не проходит хотя при сравнении они обсолютно одинаковые.
    >>> print (insert)
    INSERT INTO name_1(Number_biulding, Date_pay, Day_fine, Summa) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)
    >>> print (insert_value)
    (5, 5, 5, 5)
    и при 
    >>> print (sql_2)
    INSERT INTO name_1(Number_biulding, Date_pay, Day_fine, Summa) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    >>> print (sql_3)
    (5, 5, 5, 5)
    """



get_table()


# Завершаем транзакцию
con.commit()
# Закрываем объект-курсор
cur.close() 
# Закрываем соединение               
con.close()  

помогите пожайлуста исправить. 
Вот что выдает: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 12 supplied.
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

fn = r'D:\temp\test.xlsx'

# read & parse all excel sheets into a dictionary (keys - sheet names, values - pandas DataFrames)
dfs = pd.read_excel(fn, sheet_name=None)

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'D:\temp\output.sqlite')

# save DataFrames as SQLite tables
for tab, df in dfs.items():
    df.to_sql(tab, conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```